# Alert box in MVC4?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

This is what Im tying to make a alert box for ActionLink. But it doesn't work.

```
@Html.ActionLink("ADD", "BrandListComfirmed", new { id = item.brand_id }, new { onsubmit = "return confirm('Are u sure you want this brand? " + item.brand_name + "');" })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no `onsubmit` event for an anchor. Use `onclick` instead:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "ADD", 
    "BrandListComfirmed", 
    new { 
        id = item.brand_id 
    }, 
    new { 
        onclick = "return confirm('Are u sure you want this brand? " + item.brand_name + "');" 
    }
)
```

Comment: thank you. Can I use an alert box in Controller before I db.savechange?

Comment: No, `alert` is a javascript function, it can only be used on the client. The controller runs on the server.